# Cannot bind List<T> data to listview in android

Tags: android-listview

I try to show custom list data to simple listview but listview does not show correctly list data value.

This is source ...

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context, R.style.cust_dialog);

            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.orgcode);
            dialog.setTitle("Product List...");

            Button btnchkOk = (Button) dialog
                    .findViewById(R.id.btnOrgCodeOk);
            Button btnchkCancel = (Button) dialog
                    .findViewById(R.id.btnOrgCodeCancel);
            ListView lvlOrgCode = (ListView) dialog
                    .findViewById(R.id.lvlOrgCode);

            // prevent touch outer side
            dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);                

            List<Object> orglist = new ArrayList();
            List<OrgcodeInfo> orgcodeList = new ArrayList<OrgcodeInfo>();

            orgcodeList = _CashSaleLoginLogic
                    .OrgCodeList("Select ORG_CODE as [Org Code] , ORG_NAME From VW_MainLogin Where USER_ID = '"
                            + UserInfo.Role.toLowerCase() + "'");               

             ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, orgcodeList) {
            };
```

This is incorrect data

[image]

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to set arrayAdapter to listView . Hear your listView object is  `lvlOrgCode` 
and your created adapter is
`ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, orgcodeList)`

now add this line in your program :

```
lvlOrgCode.setAdapter(adapter);
```

i think it would help you.